# how to remove the linebreak after one bibitem in article+bibtex environment

Tags: spacing, bibtex

I recently encountered the following problem. Here is a sample of tex
file I used

```
\documentclass{article}
...
\begin{document}
...
\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

However, the output will be something like

```
References
[1] ...
(a new line)
[2] ...
```

The new line inserted between two bibitems looked a little bit strange and I wish there is a way to remove it. It seems that `amsart` class has this feature as default but sadly I still prefer `article` class or else I need modify my tex file quit a lot.

So is there any way to remove the annoying new line within `article` class? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix would be to use `natbib` and the `plainnat` bibliography style. Then you can set the length of the `\bibsep` to 0.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt}
\begin{document}
...
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It did the work pretty well, just I didn't quite like the style of natbib... Nonetheless, I just googled a package called compactbib.sty which does exactly what I need after a few modifications. 

Thank you again:)

Comment: This had no effect for me :(

Comment: @Anonymous Did you delete your `.aux` files and recompile?